# UEFI Boot Manager - Thinkpad Yoga - Boot Menu

Tags: boot, uefi, thinkpad

I'm trying to set up a dual boot system on my new Thinkpad Yoga and I have a couple of questions related to its UEFI Boot Manager.

On power up I can press F12 in order to pop up a Boot Menu in which I'm able to select among the entries that I have set using the UEFI shell command bcfg. Now I would like to know if it is possible to instruct the UEFI Boot Manager in order to display the Boot Menu without pressing the F12 key.

When I use bcfg boot dump within a UEFI shell in order to see the possible entries of the Boot Manager I can see options like these:

```
Option: 10. Variable: Boot0010 
Desc - Setup
DevPath - FvFile(86488440-41BB-42C7-93AC-450FBF7766BF)
Optional- N
Option: 11. Variable: Boot0011 
Desc - Boot Menu
DevPath - FvFile(126A762D-5758-4FCA-8531-201A7F57F850)
Optional- N
```

however even if I set the Boot Menu option to be the first:

```
bcfg boot mv 11 1
```

the Boot Menu does not appear without pressing F12.

I want to do so mainly because pressing F12 cause an irritating motherboard beep which I cannot disable, and because I'm curious about the possibility of setting up a dual boot system without installing an additional bootloader. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this isn't possible (I've got an X230 and I'm pretty sure it isn't possible with this model and I assume there's no difference with Yoga), but you could install an EFI bootmanager like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).  I'd prefer this approach since normally it's a lot easier to change a bootloader's configuration than fiddling with `efibootmgr` et al.

Comment: rEFInd suggests using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) as part of it's [installation on Windows](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows). I found that EasyUEFI was exactly the tool I needed to be able to edit the boot menu to both move the elements on the boot menu and delete them.